# Chrome extension to keep left sidebar tucked away in Gmail

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

On the Gmail page, there are two ways the left sidebar is displayed. One, always expanded. Two, collapsed view, which expands when mouse is hovered. I know my folder/label icons/colors so, the sidebar auto-expanding is a distraction for me and would like to keep it collapsed.

I was able to inspect the Gmail page using Chrome's DevTools and determine the element and it's class name. I was able to remove the "mouseenter" Event Listener using Chrome's DevTools from the corresponding element to achieve my goal. But on page refresh, the "mouseenter" listener is back again, so to make my life easier, I am in the process of creating a chrome extension to keep the left sidebar in Gmail tucked away and not respond to "mouseenter".

I am new to javascript and writing chrome extensions, but have gotten as far to register a content script that runs when Gmail page has loaded.

When I do this, the sidebar is hidden, so I know that I have the right element

```
var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName("nH oy8Mbf nn aeN bhZ");
sidebar[0].style.display = "none";
```

But, when I try to remove the event listener, it does not work (sidebar continues to respond to "mouseenter").

```
var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName("nH oy8Mbf nn aeN bhZ");
sidebar[0].removeEventListener("mouseenter", null);
```

*Note: since I couldn't determine the function for the mouseenter listener, I am passing 'null' as the 2nd (function) argument*

I also tried to override the listener using this block of code (saw it on stackoverflow):

```
var sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName("nH oy8Mbf nn aeN bhZ");

sidebar[0].addEventListener("mouseenter", function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

I haven't had success so far. If there are any alternate approaches or any issue with my approach, please let me know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think `nH oy8Mbf nn aeN bhZ` is a valid CSS class name. - But it turns out that `getElementsByClassName` still finds it...

Comment: I am fairly sure that class name is not an issue, because I am finding the right element and am able to hide it using a command like this:

`sidebar[0].style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using CSS and a little bit of Javascript. This approach doesn't remove the Event listener. Source for the Chrome Extension is available here:

https://github.com/workingsunil/chrome-extension-hidden-sidebar

Features:

1. On mouse hover, the left sidebar no longer auto expands/collapses
2. Unread mail counts shown on labels
3. When the "more" button is clicked, fullsize sidebar is shown

Hat tip to [gmail-chrome-extension-boilerplate](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail-chrome-extension-boilerplate) for the page load wait.